# Changing Delimiter in Directory List

Tags: batch-file, ms-access-2016

I'm a little bit stuck and need some help.

Currently have a process where completed work is stored in a directory as `.txt` files *(the filename describes what the job was eg. `Job1_Machine1_Randomly generated number.txt`)*.

What I would like to do is run a dirlist via a batch file to easily extract the days work. I currently do this as:

```
dir *.* /s | find "%date%" >dirlisttoday.txt
```

The next part of my process is to upload the list into an Access database for matching and tracking, I use the files date and time stamp as a 'completed date'.

Currently the second process requires a manual manipulation as the Access import from `.txt` file only allows a single delimiter, *(I have spaces between date/times and underscores in the title)*.

I can't use fixed width imports as `Machine1` can vary in length. The directory is also used by other processes which can't be changed, so changing the filename isn't possible either.

I want to automate this process so it can be carried out by Windows Task Scheduler. Is there a line of script which can be added to my batch file to alter the directory list I create `dirlisttoday.txt` from:

```
31/08/2017 12:30 Job1_Machine1_Randomly generated number.txt
```

to:

```
31/08/2017 12:30   Job1 Machine1 Randomly generated number.txt
```

Comment: Environment variable substitution: `SET "VAR=%VAR:_= %"`

Comment: And the `SET` command also has a way to extract individual characters from the environment variable, which could be used to get the extra spacing your example seems to suggest.  `SET /A` can be used for integer arithmetic operations.